# Can't insert data table using sqlbulkcopy

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

This is my code with the following columns and in the DB, those columns are `nvarchars`.

```
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction);

bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Test";
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Number", "Code");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Type", "Type");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Group", "Group");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Short Text", "ShortText");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Text", "Description");
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
```

I am trying to insert a whole data table in a DB, using bulk copy but I am getting this error:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.

Comment: You'll need to show us some table structures, code and so forth - just with that error, we cannot possibly help you ..... - see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: please check you source data. There might be invalid data in the source.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It *may* be caused by a too-short-column. If your ShortText column is defined as NVARCHAR(30) and you have a 40 character string, you may get that error. See here for example: http://forums.asp.net/p/1228890/2212376.aspx

Comment: Bingo! This was what my problem was. Good tip, and an example of the error message not telling you the 'whole story'.

Comment: Awesome! Saved my life ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have another answer for this question, maybe it can come in handy for someone. If you have a String which contains `"` (quotation mark), you get this error message too. At least I just got this error message, and I searched for the wrong row, and I found this. As I removed the quotation marks, the error disappeared.

Comment: I spent hours trying to resolve this error and this turned out to be the culprit for me too. I just copied all of the data from my source database into an Excel spreadsheet, searched the sheet for the bad character and found one instance.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with quotation marks, or insert them back after import somehow?