# SqlBulkCopy, string variable enclosed in quotes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex

I am receiving this error when trying to do a bulk copy to my SQL Server db in my ASP.NET MVC project

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.

I have looked through similar issues and found 1 which helped me pinpoint my issue:
[c# can't insert data table using sqlbulkcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273243/c-sharp-cant-insert-data-table-using-sqlbulkcopy). I would like to point out the answer given by KatieAmber:

> I have another answer for this question, maybe it can come in handy for someone. If you have a String which contains " (quotation mark), you get this error message too. At least I just got this error message, and I searched for the wrong row, and I found this. As I removed the quotation marks, the error disappeared.

So when looking at the data in my `.csv` I noticed that the GPS coordinates were all enclosed in quotes, like this "-29.721447,31.066920". Of course in this case, I immediately realised that I cannot remove the quotes as this single lat, long value would then become 2 separate values, separated by the comma.

So my question is, is there a possible way to work around this? Could I possibly patch my `SqlBulkCopy` to accept the quoted string? Or maybe specify another separator?

Comment: I have never seen `SqlBulkCopy` choke on a quote - `SqlBulkCopy` is raw TDS, and TDS knows how columns work (the T is "tabular"); something seems very wrong here... what is the *source* of this data? are you sure this isn't simply a column mismatch (type, length) or a glitch in the *reader*?

Comment: Did you check [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18149263/2655508](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18149263/2655508)

Comment: What length is your nvarchar column? Are you trying to insert a string that is longer than the maximum length?

Comment: @heslacher I have seen that. the answer doesn't help me.

Comment: @MarcGravell the source is an excel file that had been converted to csv. I can confirm that there is no mismatch in the columns. How would I identify a glitch in the reader?

Comment: @GarethD it is definately not longer that the maximum specified in sql

Comment: I am going to attempt using a different separator, will notify here with the results

Comment: @AbdulG can you simply tell us the size of the column? that would really really help. How are you reading the CSV? what API are you using? are you filling a DataTable? or are you using an IDataReader? if so: which one?

Comment: @MarcGravell the size is nvarchar(30), and I am filling a DataTable. Also the file is read in with the StreamReader

Comment: @AbdulG right; so, if the CSV reader has done its job correctly, the final actual value there doesn't include quotes - it is the string containing the value `-29.721447,31.066920`; if it was me, I would check the DataTable and find the maximum length (over the rows) for each string-based column in turn. I suspect the error is not where you think it is.

Comment: Something like: http://pastie.org/9349535

Comment: @MarcGravell I see, maybe I have just been lead astray by that answer I mentioned. I'll look into your suggestion.