# InvalidOperation type String from data source Error

Tags: c#

I have encounter an error which is

> *The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.*

on below code. This code I been use since last month and its working, I'm not sure whats the root cause of this. Kindly advise

```
DataTable sheetTable = loadSingleSheet(@"" + var_SourceFilePath + "MBF_Cancel_Temp.xlsx" + "", sheetName);
```

loading sheet as below

```
private static DataTable loadSingleSheet(string fileName, string sheetName)
    {
        DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = returnConnection(fileName))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // retrieve the data using data adapter
            OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "] ", conn);
            sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);

            //OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand("select F1, F2, F3, F4, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15, F5 from [" + sheetName + "] WHERE F5 = '100,000'", conn);
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand("select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10 from [" + sheetName + "] ", conn);
            //OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand("select NO, LOC, [EFF DATE], [EXP DATE], [NAME], [I#C], [D#O#B], [ADD1], [ADD2], [ADD3], [ADD4], [ADD5], [P#C], [BEN#NAME], [BEN#I#C] from [" + sheetName + "] ", conn);
            //conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(var_MSDBConn);
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "AMB_Cancel_Temp";

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }

            conn.Close();

        }
        return sheetData;
    }


private static DataTable loadSingleSheet(string fileName, string sheetName)
{
    DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = returnConnection(fileName))
    {
        conn.Open();
        // retrieve the data using data adapter
        OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "] ", conn);
        sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);

        //OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand("select F1, F2, F3, F4, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15, F5 from [" + sheetName + "] WHERE F5 = '100,000'", conn);
        OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand("select F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10 from [" + sheetName + "] ", conn);
        //OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand("select NO, LOC, [EFF DATE], [EXP DATE], [NAME], [I#C], [D#O#B], [ADD1], [ADD2], [ADD3], [ADD4], [ADD5], [P#C], [BEN#NAME], [BEN#I#C] from [" + sheetName + "] ", conn);
        //conn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(var_MSDBConn);
        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "AMB_Cancel_Temp";

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
        }

        conn.Close();

    }
    return sheetData;
}
```

Comment: is var_SourceFilePath  variable ?

Comment: `@""` results to an empty string (and so does `""`). Are you sure you meant that? What do you expect `@"" + var_SourceFilePath + "MBF_Cancel_Temp.xlsx" + ""` to produce? What is `var_SourceFilePath `? What does that method do?

Comment: What `loadSingleSheet` method do exactly?

Comment: var_SourceFilePath was the location path where to get the excel sheet.

Comment: The code posted has nothing to do with the question. Please post the code that produces the error *in the question itself*. not as an answer. Also specify *where* the error occurs, whether you tried debugging the code and what happened during debugging.

Comment: Why do you call `dr.Read()`? `WriteToServer(dr)` will do so itself until all rows are read. At best you lose the first row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't insert data table using sqlbulkcopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273243/cant-insert-data-table-using-sqlbulkcopy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can occur if one of the table's columns is too short to store the value you are trying to store. This will occur for example if you have a 40-character string but your field is defined as `nvarchar(30)`. It's not possible to be certain though, as you havent posted the table's definition.

The solution is to check the size of your columns and ensure they are large enough to accept the values you want to input. An alternative is to truncate the size of the incoming values to the size of the columns.

Comment: Hi Pana , I resolved the issue with other method. Thanks for the advise